# Chrome bug, transform:rotate and background-attachment fixed

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

I can not understand why rotae affects fixed shifting image. On IE, FF, Opera, everything is fine. Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/4sUCp/10/ . Please help.

html:

```
<div class="hover">HOVER ME</div>
<div>
    <div class="img" style="left:0;">
        <div class="hover">HOVER ME</div>
    </div>
    <div class="img img2" style="right:0;">
        <div class="hover">HOVER ME</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

css:

```
.img {
    position: absolute;
    margin-top: 20px;
    height: 200px;
    width: 50%;
    background: url("http://goo.gl/jY7Kwv");
    background-size: cover;
    background-attachment: fixed;
}
.img2 {
    background: url('http://hq-wallpapers.ru/wallpapers/2/hq-wallpapers_ru_girls_9386_1920x1080.jpg');
    background-size: cover;
    background-attachment: fixed;

}
.img:hover {
    width: 80%;
    z-index: 2;
}
.hover {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index:1;
    transition: 0.5s;
}
.hover:hover {
    transform: translateY(10px) rotate(90deg);
}
```

Comment: Adding `z-index: -1;` to the text seems to fix the problem. [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Ruddy/4sUCp/7/)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Not sure why chrome behaves as such, but seems like using `z-index` fixes the issue, I searched for similar Bugs but none seems to be reporting the same behavior, so it might be that it's a bug.

```
.hover {
    z-index:1;
    /* Other properties */
}
```

<kbd>[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/4sUCp/8/)</kbd>

The fact is that `background-attachment` property has nothing to do with other elements, moreover, your element is positioned `absolute` and so it's already out of the flow, since non other browser behaves as such, we can take it as a bug.

Comment: Meh, I was close. For that matter same thing, just I was putting it behind the image.

Comment: Thank you to the demonstration. I used code like this: http://jsfiddle.net/4sUCp/10/ here and again see the problem, which is the only chrome 
Can somehow better to redesign the html and css?

Comment: @user2978570 Your text is not even visible, can you share a mockup of what you are trying to achieve and I can help you out with a better CSS

Comment: @Mr. Alien I've updated the demo http://jsfiddle.net/4sUCp/11/. If you hover over the element .hover inside .img, jumping picture.

Comment: @user2978570 I can see that already, but the design doesn't look great, I would like you to create a mockup so that I can provide you some nice solution, so explain in the question with a wireframe that what you are trying to do

Answer (score 5):

This can also be resolved by removing `position:relative` from `.img` (I can't see a reason for the selector to have this property based on the OPs example):

```
.img {
    margin-top: 20px;
    height: 200px;
    width: 100%;
    background: url("http://goo.gl/jY7Kwv");
    background-size: cover;
    background-attachment: fixed;
}
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/4sUCp/9/

As Mr Alien has mentioned, this maybe a bug with Chrome, with your current CSS.

I would advise setting your own `z-index` if using `position: relative | absolute` with multiple elements on the same level. If this isn't set, `z-index: auto` is applied. Don't let the machines take over your CSS.

Comment: Thank you to the demonstration. I used code like this: http://jsfiddle.net/4sUCp/10/ 
Can somehow better to redesign the html and css?